# Formation of Image by Mirrors

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

We know that,Concave mirror reflects the light rays and the image is formed in front of the mirror but we see the image in the mirror itself.So how it is possible and if i am wrong at somewhere then please correct me

[image]

For ex. Here the image is formed on the focus which is not on the Mirror but we see the image on mirror.

Comment: You sure we see an image on the mirror _in this particular case_? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 2):

You **think** that you see the image **in** the mirror because the real image is formed at a position which devoid of any objects close to it  which can be used for reference.  It is difficult to get the eye to focus on a real image formed in "thin air".

The only other object which you can focus on is the mirror and so you see both the real image and the mirror but cannot ascertain there relative separation.

[image]

Get the mirror to form an image of a distant object as in the left hand diagram.
Where I have the label pin place a bit of tracing paper (a screen which allows some light through) and move it towards and away from the mirror as shown in the left diagram until a sharp image of the distant object if formed.
You will note that the image is not formed "in the mirror" but in front of the mirror although the mirror can also be seen.

You can identify the position of the real image formed by the mirror by using the [method of no-parallax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2w-V-mD23uw).
Pin a pin or small object between the mirror and the eye and you should see the pin and the distant object.
Move your eye left to right as per the right-hand diagram and adjust the position of the pin until there is no relative movement between the pin and the image of the distant object - a position of no parallax.
The pin is now located in the same region as the image of the distant object.

[Here you will find the same method described](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314519/104696) for the real image formed by a converging lens.

Answer (score 0):

When an object is placed between infinity and focus of the concave mirror, the image formed is real i.e it can be obtained on a screen. All real images are inverted. When you look into a concave mirror while being outside its focal length, you observe an inverted image. The image is formed in front of the mirror on the eyes of the observer acting as a screen. For the image to be virtual and erect i.e to be formed on the mirror, you have to be inside the focal length of the mirror e.g when we look into a shaving mirror (a concave mirror with large radius of curvature), we observe a virtual and erect image of ourselves on the mirror.