# Seeing virtual image in convex lens of object kept beyond focal point

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Beyond the focal point, $f$, a convex lens only forms real image. However, I see an inverted virtual image of a distant object when looking at the lens from a distance.

If the image of the distant object converges near the focus and then diverges from that point towards our eyes then the image should appear to be in mid air, but it isn't. It's appears to be in the lens.

Why is that so?

Edit: if the image is from mid air it should look like a hologram doesn't it.
But it doesn't look like one.

Comment: You are seeing a real image in mid air.  Related [Real images and their formation](Real images and their formation)

Comment: Hi Lelouche, Welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! It appears that you have two questions in one post. Perhaps consider editing this one to just refer to the inverted image, and post another one referring to their appeared location.

Comment: I believe both the questions have one answer, whether the image is in the lens or in mid air

Comment: @Farcher But it doesn't appear to be in mid air, it appears to be inside the lens

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314519/

Comment: I think it is only because our eye is not accustomed to view images in air that we see the image in the lens. If you tilt your head you may be able to see the separation between image and lens.

Comment: @LeloucheLamperouge Use a pin to locate the image and I think you will find that it is a real image.

Comment: @JeeveshJuneja ya that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I post this as an answer, as I do not have enough reputation to post a comment. It should be easier to locate the image if the lens is far away enough from your eyes that you can see the image with both eyes, as you will be able to judge distances better.
I recall having heard it from someone (if I recall well what he said, as I had the same question as you), I never verified it. But it looks sensible.