# How a image formed by circular glass slab?

Tags: geometric-optics

Take a circular glass slab, and mark something on a curved side, now see the image of the mark from opposite side of the slab. I observed that it is magnified, why is it so?

In this, only one refraction is taking place, on the observer side.

Using ray diagrams I tried to form the image. Image formed is real and forming outside the slab, but I don't observe the image outside the slab. It just appears to be magnified.

I have added an image, may be it will clarify what I am trying to ask.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is very difficult to localize a picture, your eye adjusts to the rim of your slab an your brain beliefs the image there.  When you know, where the image should be, you can put a little frame there or something else, your eye can adjust to, and you will see the image in the calculate distance, or you take small bulb from a flashlight, instead of you mark and see the real image on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

You are imagining that the image is formed inside the sphere but a real image is formed outside the glass sphere on the side remote from you marked point.

You can use the method of no-parallax to identify the position of the real image as [described in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/314564/104696).

Leeuewenhoek, a Dutchman 1632 - 1723, made the first practical microscopes using small glass spheres as the objectives and here is a photograph taken of diatoms using one of his microscopes with a magnification of 300x.

[image]

To achieve such an image the objective produced a real image with is further magnified by an eyepiece.  Your glass sphere will also produce a real image but not that it might be fairly distorted.

Comment: I will try the no parallax method and the update the question. Thanks. BTW I am not talking about glass sphere. I am talking about circular glass slab, and observing from the curved side. You can see this image (https://png.pngitem.com/pimgs/s/532-5326252_circular-concrete-slab-nopin-nopin-circle-hd-png.png), but slabs have more height.